# Shrink Look up content in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, list-view

We are using a list(Source) with 1100 items to be looked up to another list(destination),destination list is also a large one. I would like to know, whether we can shorten the look up based on any conditions.

Look up column: APP NAME(primary), App data, App Details...etc

We would like to add a new column in the destination list/source list, which can sort app names based on the first letter like A-H, H-M, M-Z. Will this decrease complexity and load time?

How can we accomplish it? Is there any alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a Filtered Lookup Column, and it's a feature that SharePoint doesn't support OOTB. There ARE, however, several solutions available for creating your own.

If you want the filtered lookup functionality available from within the normal list interface, you'll want to look into a custom solution like [this one on Codeplex](https://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/). This solution, and others like it that you can buy or code yourself, get installed on the farm as a solution and (once activated for the site) allows you to filter lookup results based on a CAML query.

Another option is to use jQuery behind the New/Edit form itself. Something like the code below will filter results dynamically as the results load. Note that you'll need the [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to make this work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Filter bidders by selected Territory
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    listName: "Project Bids",
    relationshipList: "Bidders",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Territory",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Full_x0020_Name",
    parentColumn: "Territory",
    childColumn: "Bidders"
   });
});
```

Lastly, if your users are accessing the information via a custom interface like a DVWP, then you can filter results directly in the XSLT, either via a filtered join or a CAML query.

Comment: Sorry, I am not having control over the farm to publish it.Is it possible to spilt the source list to 3 or 4 to make this achieve?.or via using designer tool?.

Comment: If you have access to the site via Designer, then I would recommend the latter option using the code. You'll need to download that SPServices library and put both it AND jQuery somewhere in the site. I usually create a "js" folder in the Style Library and put it there. Then you need to call both scripts in your master page (near the top where all the other script links are).